# How to edit (Image)Views asynchronously?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to animate an ImageView with a list of pictures, iterating through them quickly, so that
it creates the impression of an animation. Sadly it does give the alert: **Skipped 391 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**

This is my Main-Activity which implements the Animator-interface.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       
            GlobalScope.launch {
                show(Action.Idle)
            }
    }
```

My Animator show() function (runs the Runnables with android.os.Handler):

```
fun show(action: Action){
                getHandler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
                when (action) {
                    Action.MoveRight -> getHandler().post(getRight())
                    Action.MoveUp -> getHandler().post(getUp())
                    Action.MoveDown -> getHandler().post(getDown())
                    Action.MoveLeft -> getHandler().post(getLeft())
                    Action.Idle -> getHandler().post(idle())
                }
    }
```

My idle function (anim.idle is an array of Ints/Drawables):

```
fun idle() = object : Runnable{
        override fun run() {
                val anim = getAnimation()
                repeat(anim.idle!!.size){
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread {
                        binding.figure.setImageResource(anim.idle[it])
                        binding.figure.invalidate()
                    }
                        Thread.sleep(500)
            }
            getHandler().postDelayed(this,5000)
        }
    }
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, this seems like a very interesting question, i'm not sure how you would achieve this because i don't think you could change views on the background thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AnimationDrawable` to have the `ImageView` show a sequence of pictures, see also the guide to [Animate drawable graphics](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation)

In a nutshell, you declare a `animation-list` drawable resource and set it as the `View` background (or foreground, according to your requirements). You can then obtain the `AnimationDrawable` from the `View` at runtime and use it to start the animation.

In my small example, I used some vector drawables with different tints

[image]

to create the `animation-list` in **res/drawable/colored_androids.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_android_blue_24dp" android:duration="250"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_android_mint_24dp" android:duration="250"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_android_green_24dp" android:duration="250"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_android_mint_24dp" android:duration="250"/>
</animation-list>
```

My `Activity` has a field for the `AnimationDrawable`

```
private lateinit var coloredAndroidsAnimation: AnimationDrawable
```

and in `onCreate()` the following lines are required for the setup:

```
findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_animated).apply {
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colored_androids)
    coloredAndroidsAnimation = background as AnimationDrawable

    setOnClickListener{
        coloredAndroidsAnimation.start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think you can change a view that is attached to the UI from a background thread, you can create/edit views on a background thread (I do this lots)

So a possible solution might be to programmatically create a series of ImageViews in the background. It might then be possible to measure them with the same parameters as the UI in the background thread as measurement can be costly (not sure if they would be re-measured when added to the UI)

Then in the UI thread your loop would `add` and `remove` Views from the parent view.

Comment: I implemented your idea, but this error is still occuring. **Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.** 
And I don't understand why this error keeps coming, since I change the image of this one view just two times a second.